# Hibernate Search Indexing Existing Data

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search 4.4.2 Final for my Application. When a new data is added. it is being indexed immediately, however, I need the Full Text Search to work on old entities. How do I reindex existing data with multiple tenants? I already tried looking at the documentation however this piece somehow did not index the data.

The code run succesfully with no errors However when I checked the indexes through Luke. no existing index/data was found. Am I doing this the right way? btw I am using PostgresSQL for my database with multitenancy

In my controller

```
@Override
    @RequestMapping(value = RELOAD_URL, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String reloadIndex() {
        patientService.reloadIndex();
        return "OK";
    }
```

In my patientService

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void reloadIndex() {
        patientRepo.reloadIndex();
    }
```

in my patientRepo.reloadIndex

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = 
                    Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

    try {

       fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // Exception handling
         e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Comment: This looks correct. Have you looked at the logs? It should show you that something is going on. You might have to set it to debug even trace though. As it stands now you are not providing enough information to provide more help. How do you indexed entities look like? Where and how to you call the mass indexer? ...

Comment: @Hardy I've updated the code.  The MassIndexer is being called inside a Spring Managed Repository Layer and that repository is called by a service layer and called by a controller. I can't seem to find the logs for this. I just followed configuration I found on the documentation.it did not mention how to configure the logs for this